# Can we modify the access modifier of the parent member variable or method in the subclass？

Tags: java

I saw someone write:

> The visibility of protected members in subclasses can be modified.

Then I was confused, I know the access modifier of a method in a parent class could be modified in its implementation, see below:

```
class Parent {
    protected void m1(){}
}

class SubClass extends Parent {
    
    @Override
    public void m1() {
        super.m1();
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to modify the protected access modifier of a member variable to public in the subclass. What is the code implementation like?

Comment: You can't. So probably that "someone" was only talking about methods. You may want to consider linking your source for additional context.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry the source is not written in English. I think he should make it clear that the protected members are methods rather vague members.

Answer (score -2):

Access Modifiers can be changed in child  class but there are some certain rules which have to follow-

**There are four types of access modifiers available in java:**

```
Default – No keyword required
Private
Protected
Public
```

**Method Overriding with Access Modifiers**
*Their is Only one rule while doing Method overriding with Access modifiers i.e.*

**Rule :** *If you are overriding any method, overridden method (i.e. declared in subclass) must not be more restrictive.*

Access modifier restrictions in decreasing order:

```
private
default
protected
public
```

i.e. private is more restricted then default and default is more restricted than protected and so on.

**We can change the access level of fields, constructors, methods in subclass by applying the access modifier on it.**

**Example:**

```
class Parent {
     private void m1(){}
     void m2(){}
     protected void m3(){}
     public void m4(){}
}

class SubClass extends Parent {
    /*
    @Override
    private void m1() {  super.m1(); }  // not allow any modifier shows compile time error
    */
    @Override
    void m2() {  super.m2(); }       // allow default, protected, public only
    @Override
    protected void m3() {  super.m3();  } // allow protected, public only
    @Override
    public void m4() {  super.m4();  }    // allow public only
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the specific point of the question